How to make markdown.js find the explicit language from a code block rendered from GFM
I am processing a markdown code block using GFM, and it's rendering like so:
<div class="language-powershell">
  <div class="highlight">
    <pre class="highlight">
      <code>...</code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>

I am using highlight.js for syntax highlighting, which requests the custom language like so:
<pre><code class="language-powershell">...</code></pre>

I'm not sure how to bridge the gap here, because the highlight.js language auto-detection is incorrectly guessing the type, and I can't seem to render the code block from markdown the way it wants. Is there a way I can adjust either side of the equation to render compliant to the other? Or is there an alternative to highlight.js that will work out of the box?
